# Nginx Subdomain redirect to static URL

Tags: redirect, nginx, static, subdomain

I have a domain that I can browse to via `example.com:1234`. Now I do not want to always have to type the port at the very end, but rather have nginx redirect me to the static URL when browsing a subdomain eg. `status.example.com`.

I have tried writing a redirect, but it didn't work at all.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name status.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com:1234;
}
```

Where's my error? Is it the server block? Am I missing something basic here?

Comment: you can try using proxy for that, [ngx_http_proxy_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try configuration as below,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name status.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:1234;
    }
}
```

For reference use [NGINX Reverse Proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) and [Module ngx_http_proxy_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html)

Comment: Thanks, this does work like a charm :)
Could you point out what the problem with my config was?

Comment: `return 301` is a HTTP redirect, which will redirect browser to argument provided (`$scheme://www.example.com:1234`), but proxy will be a proxy between browser and target.

Comment: Ahh, sounds reasonable. Thank you very much for the input.